# Advice for learning concepts

Tags: self-learning, learning

Apart from solving textual problems what should be done  for understanding concepts deeply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is do your best to have an "intuitive" understanding if nothing else, and read the text that way (example below).  Then practice your technical understanding by commiting things to memory and doing problems (and any other usual study techniques)

So for an example, say you are reading and come across the sentence: *"Given $n,N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $n<N$, then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $n+\epsilon < N$"*

Before moving on, you can do 2 things.  One is draw a picture.  And the other is re-read the sentence in a way that makes perfect sense to you: *"Given 2 numbers one smaller than the other, there is always space between them"*

By doing these 2 things, you are building a bridge between formal math and natural problem solving skills.  With enough practice it should become easier and should definitely help understanding math as a whole